# Datebox useFocus bug in iOS devices

Tags: ios, jquery-mobile, datebox

I am using calendar mode of `Datebox` with my `jQuery` Mobile project, everything works fine but when I use `useFocus` to open calendar wherever I click on the input field, it isn't stable in iPhone (or other iOS devices), sometimes it opens and many times it acts like crashing. But the same is working good in Desktop browsers, when I use without `useFocus` it works right in mobile devices also, I see same stability issue in [plugin website](http://dev.jtsage.com/jQM-DateBox2/demos/opt/open.html) demos too. How can we correct this issue?